# Permalinks not working for custom taxonomy on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have a custom post type registered as follows:

```
register_post_type( 'gs_business_listings',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Local Businesses' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Local Businesses' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
            'taxonomies'  => array( 'category', 'gs_business_listing_region' ),
      'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions'),
            'register_meta_box_cb' => array($this,'add_meta_boxes'),
            'rewrite' => array('slug'=> apply_filters('goosesoft-coupons-archive-url', 'local-businesses'))
            )
  );
```

and for this custom post type I have a custom taxonomy which is registered as follows:

```
register_taxonomy(
            'gs_business_listing_region',
            'gs_business_listings',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => 'Regions',
                    'singular_name' => 'Region',
                ),
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'region', 'hierarchical' => true ),
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
            )
        );
```

This works on the admin side. Everything is as expected. `Regions` shows in the `Local Businesses` submenu.  I can save the Regions for a specific post.

But permalinks are not working for the taxonomies.  What I need seems pretty straight forward and would be what I expect default behavior to be.
I need the taxonomy url to be `www.example.com/region/a-region` where `a-region` is one of the taxonomies. But when I go to a url like that it does not work.  More puzzling is that `get_term_link()` returns a url in exactly that format, but I get a 404 error on the very link that returns.

What could I be missing?

Comment: Did you flush rewrite rules after adding the taxonomy?

Comment: See my answer below.  I was writing it when you posted. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There was nothing wrong with my code above. I found the answer at the bottom of the [Taxonomies page in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#404_Error):

> If your site uses custom permalinks, you will need to flush your
>   permalink structure after making changes to your taxonomies, or else
>   you may see a "Page Not Found" error. Your permalink structure is
>   automatically flushed when you visit Settings > Permalinks in your
>   WordPress dashboard.

In my plugin I already had `flush_rewrite_rules();` being called upon deactivation, and I had deactivated and reactivated it several times.  The fact that this didn't work really threw me for a loop.

But as soon as I visited `Setting > Permalinks` it all worked correctly!

Comment: You're right about my answer. It's pretty much a pointless answer so I've removed it. Probably shouldn't have been answering while distracted. You should flush the rewrite rules on plugin activation AND deactivation and AFTER your Post Types / Taxonomies have been registered. Easy way around it is to have a callback function to be called on `init` which registers your stuff. On plugin activation, call that `init` callback function and then immediately flush rewrite rules after. If you have a plugin settings page, you could also implement rewrite rule flushing when saving plugin settings page.

Comment: I was flushing on activation and deactivation.  This says that calling this function on `init` is bad practice. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

Comment: You have a function which registers your Custom Post Types and Custom Taxonomies. Both are hooked on the action `init`. The `register_activation_hook()` function is called BEFORE the `init` hook is fired. You're flushing the rewrite rules before the the rewrite rules even exist. In the callback function which is triggered on plugin activation, make a call to your function which is used to register your Custom Post Types & Custom Taxonomies. Immediately after that, make a call to `flush_rewrite_rules();`. That way, your rewrite rules are created and WP is aware of them upon plugin activation.